# C2447 in a templated class C++

Tags: c++, list, templates

I'm trying to write a class similar to `std::list` in C++.

It's my first time dealing with templated classes and I get this weird error:

> C2447: '{' missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Here is the code snippet:

```
template<typename item>
mylist<item>::iterator mylist<item>::erase(iterator pos)
{
    iterator cursor(head);
    while (cursor->next != (*pos)) ++cursor;
    if ((*cursor) == nullptr || (*cursor) == head) return iterator(nullptr);
    m_node* tmp = cursor->next->next;
    delete cursor->next;
    cursor->next = tmp;
    --m_size;
    return tmp;
}
```

The class definition:

```
template<typename item>
class mylist
{
    class m_node
    {
        friend class mylist;
        item* node_data;
        m_node* next;
    public:
        m_node()
        {
            next = nullptr;
            node_data = nullptr;
        }
        m_node(const item& ITEM): m_node()
        {
            node_data = new item(ITEM);
        }
        
        ~m_node() { delete node_data; delete next; }
    };
     m_node* head;
     m_node* tail;
     unsigned int m_size;
public:
    class iterator
    {
        friend class mylist;
        m_node* m_ptr;
    public:
        iterator()
        {
            m_ptr = nullptr;
        }
        iterator(m_node* i_ptr)
        {
            m_ptr = i_ptr;
        }
        iterator(const iterator& other)
        {
            m_ptr = other.m_ptr;
        }
        ~iterator(){}
        const iterator& operator=(const iterator& other) const
        {
            m_ptr = other.m_ptr;
            return this;
        }
        iterator& operator++()
        {
            ++m_ptr;
            return *this;
        }
        item operator->()
        {
            return *(m_ptr->node_data);
        }
        item operator*()
        {
            return *(m_ptr->node_data);
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) { return m_ptr != other.m_ptr; }
        bool operator ==(const iterator& other) { return m_ptr == other.m_ptr; }
    };
    mylist()
    {
        head = tail = new m_node();
        m_size = 0;
    }
    ~mylist()
    {
        delete head;
    }
    bool isempty() const
    {
        return head == tail;
    }
    const iterator& push_back(const item& i_item)
    {
        tail->next = new m_node(i_item);
        tail = tail->next;
        ++m_size;
        return iterator(tail);
    }
    iterator begin() const
    {
        return iterator(head);
    }
    iterator end() const
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    item& back()
    {
        return *(tail->node_data);
    }
    unsigned int size() const
    {
        return m_size;
    }
    iterator erase(iterator pos);
    void remove(item T);
};
```

The error occurs at the first curly of the function's scope.

I have read some documentations regarding this error and templated classes but could find what seems to be the error.

Comment: Where is this definition? Inside the class or somewhere else?

Comment: please show all _relevant_ codes

Comment: Please post your code/errors as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.  We also can't copy the text from images, which stops us from being able to debug your code, i.e., help you.

Comment: My crystal ball thinks that your actual code has a semicolon at the end of the first line, possibly left behind from a copy-and-paste job. It is also convinced that this being a template is a red herring.

Comment: I think the return type should be `typename mylist<item>::iterator` in the definition. I'm not sure if this is causing your problem or not. Edit : I get a different error when I try your code, but it compiles when I add `typename`.

Comment: Please read about the [mcve].

Comment: @molbdnilo false i've check for that everywhere already

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you will need a `typename` preceding the declared return type of the function template. This extra 'hint' for the compiler is required in this case because that return type [is dependent](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) on the `item` type; and, quoting from that linked cppreference page, it is *"a compound type constructed from a dependent type"*.

```cpp
template<typename item>
typename mylist<item>::iterator mylist<item>::erase(iterator pos)
{
    iterator cursor{ head };
    while (cursor->next != (*pos)) ++cursor;
    if ((*cursor) == nullptr || (*cursor) == head) return iterator(nullptr);
    m_node* tmp = cursor->next->next;
    delete cursor->next;
    cursor->next = tmp;
    --m_size;
    return tmp;
}
```

Also note that I have changed the parentheses to curly braces in the `iterator cursor{ head };` line; this is now generally accepted as better style, to avoid possible confusion between object initializers and function declarations.

Comment: I edited my answer after seeing that you *did* have the `template<typename item>` in your code, but it was 'hidden' behind the code fence (missing line-break).